# Data Storage Limits Exceeded (extra overflow buffer)

Tags: limits, data-storage

I have an issue with my *Developer License*.
When I try to create, for example, a new Opportunity the System give me the below message back:

"**Data Storage Limits Exceeded**
Your company currently has exceeded its data storage limits including an extra overflow buffer. Per our terms and conditions, we cannot permit additional data creation within our system until your company first reduces its current data storage. Please contact your company's salesforce.com administrator to resolve this. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.

Click here to return to the previous page."

I have tried to delete something like images (Mb), and still I cannot create an Opportunity. 
The same message appears if I create an Account, a Lead, etc etc.

Do you know a possible solution for that?

Andrea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Salesforce you have 2 storage categories

1) File Storage - This constitutes all the files / attachments that is uploaded in your org.

2) Data Storage - This is where your standard and custom object data resides.

Developer edition usually have very low data storage limits (5 Mb which roughly is  2.5k records (2kB -per record)). So you could delete some of the data (std / custom records) in your org and then you will be able to create new records.

You can check the storage limits by going to :

> SetUp --> Administer -> Data Management -> storage Usage

Comment: You've got a point, but the problem is in the File Storage instead: I have used **22.0 MB** instead of the *20.0 MB allowed*.